# Automatically deploy admission webhook

Tags: kubernetes

I have written Kubernetes deployment that creates a Pod, which hosts an HTTP server with [mutating] admission webhook.

I want to automatically configure Kubernetes so that it uses that HTTP server as a mutation admission webhook. I want this to happen as part of automatic deployment of your product. I want everything to be deployable using `kubectl create -f`. How can I do that?

I've read some tutorials, but they're are really complicated and involve manual steps (e.g. generating keys and certificates, approving requests, etc).
There must be some  way to just do all those things automatically...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: To register a mutating admission webhook, you have to create a [`MutatingWebhookConfiguration`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#mutatingwebhookconfiguration-v1-admissionregistration-k8s-io) object. It needs a CA bundle, i.e. TLS server certificate, so that the API server can verify the identity of the webhook. You have to automate the creation of these files.